# Is "Or you don't care about that?" natural?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Person 1: I really hope you win.

Person 2: Win?

Person 1: Yeah. Or you don't care about that?

Person 2: Not really. I'm just here to have fun.

Is person 1's second statement phrased in a correct and natural way? Or would "Or do you not care about that?" be much better?

Comment: In American English, Person 1 would probably say, "Yeah. Or don't you care?" or, "Yeah. You don't care?"

Answer (score 1):

You've got it.  It sounds much more natural to say, "Or do you not care about that?"